# Java show result on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Started making a simple GUI using netbeans and now I'm facing some problem.

I have this:

```
package my.sccsymapp;

public class sccsymapp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /*SOME CODE*/                                     
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*SOME CODE*/
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempmedespCost;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

If I run this, it works as expected. `test`is placed on my JTextField.

But what I want to do is to use `tempmedespCost.setText("test");` in some other class of my code.

I have this class:

```
package my.sccsymapp;

import java.util.*;

public class Servico extends sccsymapp{
    /*SOME CODE*/ 
    public void relat (){
    /*SOME CODE*/ 
    tempmedespCost.setText("test");
    }
    /*SOME CODE*/ 
}
```

It now says:

`tempmedespCost has private access in my.sccsymapp.sccsymapp`

So I have changed `tempmedespCost` to public.

Now no error is shown, runs without errors but `test`is not placed on my JTextField.

Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: "*Can you point me in some direction?*" Yeah, don't use GUI builders.

Comment: Badly prepared code: Simulador is shown, but of no significance to the problem. Gui-builder commands `// TODO add your handling code here:` aren't removed. When you put handling code there, remove the comment. When you understood that you have to put your code there in principle, remove the comment from the template.

Comment: @userunknown Ok. Forgot to remove that. Edited now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tempmedespCost` is defined as private in your class

`private` members can only be acceded by functions that are members of the class. Children of the class (like  `Servico`) can't access to private fields.

You can either change the visibility of `tempmedespCost` to protected or create a getter that will let you access to `tempmedespCost`

I suggest you read some documentation about Java visibility in [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Hi. that said, if `tempmedespCost` is `public`or `protected` it should work but although the program does't give me any warning it does not work as expected. Understood the getter ans setter part but now just want to understand why `public`or `protected` arn't working

Comment: @Favolas : Are you sure `protected` is not working, since both your Classes are in the same package, so anything having `Access Specifier` as `protected` within the same package, will work as `public` does. Since you are about to take a plunge into the `World of Swing`, come to a simple `Text Editor` instead of using an `IDE` to make your programs.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Don't know how I didn't work. Probably was doing something wrong. Followed `Estragon` suggestion and made it work with getters and setters